# MonboDB find and update nested array by filter if exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My backend structure is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e07702c2714a70790c0e85d"),
    // Some settings
    "data" : [
        {
            "day" : "19/01/20",
            "appointments" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5e24e0a0775894070821d2a2"),
                    "client" : {
                        "id" : "5e07702c2714a70790c0e811",
                        "fullName" : "John Smith"
                    },
                    "starts" : "1579446000"
                },
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5e24e0a0775894070821ab44"),
                    "client" : {
                        "id" : "5e07702c2714a70790c0e833",
                        "fullName" : "David Miller"
                    },
                    "starts" : "1579447800"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "day" : "20/01/20",
            "appointments" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5e24e0a0775894070821d2a2"),
                    "client" : {
                         "id" : "5e07702c2714a70790c0e844",
                         "fullName" : "John Smith"
                     },    
                    "starts" : "1579532400"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need is to insert an appointment to a specific day, that's what I do and it works:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId(calendarId)
    },
    {
        "$push": { "data.$[outer].appointments": appointment }
    },
    {
        "arrayFilters": [{ "outer.day": day }]
    }
)
```

My questions:

- How can I add the day if its object doesn't exist? what I wanna do is if the day exists, push to appointments array. If it doesn't, I need to create an object with "day" and "appointments" with a single object.
- How can I check if a certain time is not taken (the "starts")?

"arrayFilters": [{ "outer.day": day }] - day is a string variable converted from timestamp to DD/MM/YY

Comment: Use `upsert` in your update query - Reference - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert

Comment: I've already tried that, it doesn't work when a day object doesn't exist.